# Is it possible to run JS from either apex from a flow?

Tags: apex, javascript, visual-workflow, einstein, bots

I am building an einstein bot, and I want to get the url (window.location.href) of the chatbot in the MIDDLE of the einstein bot dialogue (and therefore extraprechatformdetails won't do the job here.) Einstein bots allow invoking either apex or a flow in the middle of a dialogue. My question is: can I run javascript from a flow or apex class, so that I can get the window.location.href and save it as a variable that I can reference in my bot dialogue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create [Flow Local Actions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_flow_actions.htm) to execute a client-side JavaScript.

Note that this will be an Aura Component as below

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:availableForFlowActions" access="global">
   <aura:attribute name="url" type="String" access="global" />
</aura:component>
```

**component controller**

```
({
   // When a flow executes this component, it calls the invoke method
  invoke : function(component, event, helper) {
      alert('href...' + window.location.href);
      component.set("v.url", window.location.href);
   }
})
```

**Update 1 - Local actions does not work in Autolaunched flows**

> Turns out for Einstein Bots only Auto Launched flows are supported and Auto Launched flows only allow Apex Actions and not Local actions.

In this case, just write an Apex invocable action like below

```
public with sharing class FetchCurrentURL {
 @InvocableMethod(label='Get Current URL' description='Returns Current URL')
 public static List<String> getcurrentURL() {
   System.debug(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm());
   return new List<String>{URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()};
   }
 }
```

An Auto launch flow would be as below

[image]

**Update 2- Pre-chat data can pass in window.location.href**

Looks like the easiest way to do this would be using [pre-chat data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bot_cookbook.meta/bot_cookbook/bot_cookbook_optimize_flow.htm) as discussed in the cookbook.

Create an extra field on the **LiveChatTranscript** object named "Visitor URL" and use the below

```
 embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatFormDetails = [{
 "label": "Customer Visit URL",
  "value": window.location.href,
  "displayToAgent": true,
  "transcriptFields" : ["Visitor_URL__c"]
 },
```

To learn more visit this [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bot_cookbook.meta/bot_cookbook/bot_cookbook_optimize_flow_lex.htm).

**Update 3 - Use LWC Handler to listen for the Bot and you can write your Javascript within the LWC Component.**

This option allows you to configure a LWC component that can listen for the chat messages and execute apex and Javascript.

A simple example of how all these works are shown in this [repo](https://github.com/coveooss/lwc-coveobot).

Comment: Hi Mohith, Thank you for that! I am not sure I get how to implement this. Can this be run from an autolaunched flow (only autolaunched flows can be run from an einstein bot dialogue, and not screen flows)?

Comment: @MichaelM Just updated the answer! Please check!!!

Comment: Ok thank you! And just to confirm, the url that I want to fetch is not from Salesforce itself, but from an external website (i want to invoke the apex from my einstein bot, which is placed on an external website (not a salesforce community nor a force.com site). Will that invokable apex with getSalesforceBaseUrl method still work?

Comment: It’s salesforce url! I recommend you try and let me know!! Is your site an website? I think apart from flows there must be some other way to get the url info

Comment: @MichaelM I further updated the answer. Use the pre-chat data method than going for flows or apex.

Comment: Hi Mohith, thank you so much for your continued help with this. I would use the extraPrechatFormDetails, however for this current use case I am not able to. The reason is because I need to be able to fetch the URL in the MIDDLE of an einstein bot dialogue, whereas the extraPrechatFormDetails only allow to fetch the FIRST url that the bot begins.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117783/discussion-between-mohith-shrivastava-and-michael-m).